# How to use useFetch in this app in nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, fetch, nuxt.js

```
const refreshNewToken = async () => {
   const { data } = await useFetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1");
   console.log(data.value); // return null
}
```

This app console null;

I try using useFetch nuxt but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useFetch` still works, but you're using it the wrong way. it is a composition api so it needs to be called from the top-level instance:

Good use:

```
const { data, refresh: refreshNewToken, error } = await useFetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1")

watch(data, data => console.log(data))
```